# Solving for matrices [T] and [T]', and the transition matrix Q given a basis.

Tags: linear-algebra

Problem Part 1:  [image]

I've already proved that T is a linear transformation, but I need to verify that I solved the other parts of the problem correctly.  Here's my attempt to find [T] and [T]' below:

[image]

Problem Part 2:  [image]

The columns of Q would just be the vectors of B', correct?  So, I would end up with the following for Q, Q^-1, and [T] (from part 1):

[image]

However, when I computed (Q^-1)(T)(Q), the result didn't equal to [T]' from part 1, so that means that I made a mistake in either part 1 or part 2 of the problem.  So, could someone point out where I went wrong?

Comment: One thing I noticed right away is that for the matrix $[T]'$ the vectors are row vectors and should be column vectors. That is, the actual $[T]'$ matrix should be the transpose of what you have.